# SharePoint default form validation

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to validate SharePoint form using the default validation on SharePoint,

`SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')`

This line of code validates the form but also if validation is true it submits the form, I dont want the form to be submitted, so how can we stop it from submitting after validation using the above line of code.

Comment: Can you post little more code where you are using this line of code?

Comment: I am using this code on sharepoint list newform.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I trigger the default form validation without submitting the form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92864/how-do-i-trigger-the-default-form-validation-without-submitting-the-form)

Comment: Yes I have already checked these answers, I am looking for something simple, if there is something like 2 line of code about it.